# Error in cygwin - cannot find fftw and rfftw

Tags: cygwin

When I compile a .cpp file I get the errors as in the picture. I have installed fftw3(via cygwin setup.exe) and fftw2 (manually). I am able to find fftw3.h and rfftw.h when I search for them. What am I missing?

Errors as displayed in cygwin:
[image: Errors as displayed in cygwin].

Comment: do not copy screenshot. Copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the development package content:

```
 $ cygcheck -l libfftw3-devel
/usr/include/fftw3.f
/usr/include/fftw3.f03
/usr/include/fftw3.h
/usr/include/fftw3l.f03
/usr/include/fftw3q.f03
/usr/lib/libfftw3.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3f.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3f_omp.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3f_threads.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3l.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3l_omp.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3l_threads.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3_omp.dll.a
/usr/lib/libfftw3_threads.dll.a
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/fftw3.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/fftw3f.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/fftw3l.pc
```

so the import library is `/usr/lib/libfftw3.dll.a`
and need `-lfttw3`. Same info from `pkg-config`

```
$ pkg-config --libs fftw3
-lfftw3
```